# DELETE request work with rule in SQL Server, but doesn't with Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a delete request rule with Entity Framework Core.

If I make the rule in SQL Server, it works fine, but when I try to make the relations through Entity Framework Core, I'm getting this error:

[image]

My `modelBuilder` in EF Core:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Images)
                .WithOne(x => x.Post)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.PostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

My delete method in my controller:

```
// DELETE: api/Posts/5
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePost(int id)
{
    var post = await _context.Posts.FindAsync(id);

    if (post == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
  
    _context.Posts.Remove(post);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}
```

This works:

[image]

Comment: trying adding this to dbcontext protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.images)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}

Comment: I'm getting this error when trien to use ".HasOptional"
EntityTypeBuilder<Post> does not contain a definition for “HasOptional”

Comment: Are you updating the database after making modifications to your model? Because `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` should set migration/creation command to set `Delete Rule = Cascade` in the database. Just setting it in the model and not updating the database has no effect. See [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) documentation.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm not sure what you mean sir. I use the : await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); is that what you mean?